# Как поставить кнопку по центру

Tags: javascript, css

Какой параметр нужно изменить, чтобы кнопка плавной прокрутки вверх располагалась по центру страницы, а не в правой части ?
Вот сам код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
/*********************************************** 
* Scroll To Top Control script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com) 
* Modified by www.MyBloggerTricks.com 
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use 
* Visit Project Page at http://www.dynamicdrive.com for full source code 
***********************************************/
var scrolltotop={ 
    //startline: Integer. Number of pixels from top of doc scrollbar is scrolled before showing control 
    //scrollto: Keyword (Integer, or "Scroll_to_Element_ID"). How far to scroll document up when control is clicked on (0=top). 
    setting: {startline:100, scrollto: 0, scrollduration:1000, fadeduration:[500, 100]},
    controlHTML: '<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-eV_K1uq_pdo/Tn4cpk-TF4I/AAAAAAAABo8/CHlsAWkdT6g/s800/1316886651_top.png" />', //HTML for control, which is auto wrapped in DIV w/ ID="topcontrol" 
    controlattrs: {offsetx:5, offsety:5}, //offset of control relative to right/ bottom of window corner 
    anchorkeyword: '#top', //Enter href value of HTML anchors on the page that should also act as "Scroll Up" links
    state: {isvisible:false, shouldvisible:false},
    scrollup:function(){ 
        if (!this.cssfixedsupport) //if control is positioned using JavaScript 
            this.$control.css({opacity:0}) //hide control immediately after clicking it 
        var dest=isNaN(this.setting.scrollto)? this.setting.scrollto : parseInt(this.setting.scrollto) 
        if (typeof dest=="string" && jQuery('#'+dest).length==1) //check element set by string exists 
            dest=jQuery('#'+dest).offset().top 
        else 
            dest=0 
        this.$body.animate({scrollTop: dest}, this.setting.scrollduration); 
    },
    keepfixed:function(){ 
        var $window=jQuery(window) 
        var controlx=$window.scrollLeft() + $window.width() - this.$control.width() - this.controlattrs.offsetx 
        var controly=$window.scrollTop() + $window.height() - this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety 
        this.$control.css({left:controlx+'px', top:controly+'px'}) 
    },
    togglecontrol:function(){ 
        var scrolltop=jQuery(window).scrollTop() 
        if (!this.cssfixedsupport) 
            this.keepfixed() 
        this.state.shouldvisible=(scrolltop>=this.setting.startline)? true : false 
        if (this.state.shouldvisible && !this.state.isvisible){ 
            this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:1}, this.setting.fadeduration[0]) 
            this.state.isvisible=true 
        } 
        else if (this.state.shouldvisible==false && this.state.isvisible){ 
            this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:0}, this.setting.fadeduration[1]) 
            this.state.isvisible=false 
        } 
    },

    init:function(){ 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            var mainobj=scrolltotop 
            var iebrws=document.all 
            mainobj.cssfixedsupport=!iebrws || iebrws && document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" && window.XMLHttpRequest //not IE or IE7+ browsers in standards mode 
            mainobj.$body=(window.opera)? (document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body') 
            mainobj.$control=$('<div id="topcontrol">'+mainobj.controlHTML+'</div>') 
                .css({position:mainobj.cssfixedsupport? 'fixed' : 'absolute', bottom:mainobj.controlattrs.offsety, right:mainobj.controlattrs.offsetx, opacity:0, cursor:'pointer'}) 
                .attr({title:'Scroll Back to Top'}) 
                .click(function(){mainobj.scrollup(); return false}) 
                .appendTo('body') 
            if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest && mainobj.$control.text()!='') //loose check for IE6 and below, plus whether control contains any text 
                mainobj.$control.css({width:mainobj.$control.width()}) //IE6- seems to require an explicit width on a DIV containing text 
            mainobj.togglecontrol() 
            $('a[href="' + mainobj.anchorkeyword +'"]').click(function(){ 
                mainobj.scrollup() 
                return false 
            }) 
            $(window).bind('scroll resize', function(e){ 
                mainobj.togglecontrol() 
            }) 
        }) 
    } 
}
scrolltotop.init()
</script>
```

Comment: Акелла промахнулся...
Дважды. =.=

Comment: жаль низя дважды ткнуть лайк)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот кроссплатформенный пример позиционирования кнопки по центру(включая IE):

```
 <input type="button" onClick="clicked()" id="f5">  // кнопка
 <script>
 function clicked()
 {
    el = document.getElementById("f5"); // получаем кнопку
    el.style.position="absolute";      // абсолютное позиционирование
    el.style.left=document.body.clientWidth/2-el.clientWidth/2; // Вычисления...
    el.style.top=document.body.clientHeight/2-el.clientHeight/2;
     }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var controlx=$window.scrollLeft() + $window.width() - this.$control.width() - this.controlattrs.offsetx 
var controly=$window.scrollTop() + $window.height() - this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety
```

Вот тут, если я правильно понимаю, задаются параметры расположения кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Вот если код такой использовать:

```
  init:function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var mainobj=scrolltotop
        var iebrws=document.all
        mainobj.cssfixedsupport=!iebrws || iebrws && document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" && window.XMLHttpRequest //not IE or IE7+ browsers in standards mode
        mainobj.$body=(window.opera)? (document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body')
        mainobj.$control=$('<div id="topcontrol">'+mainobj.controlHTML+'</div>')
            .css({position:mainobj.cssfixedsupport? 'fixed' : 'absolute', top:mainobj.controlattrs.offsety, right:mainobj.controlattrs.offsetx, opacity:0, cursor:'pointer'})
            .attr({title:'Scroll to Top'})
            .click(function(){mainobj.scrollup(); return false})
            .appendTo('body')
        if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest && mainobj.$control.text()!='') //loose check for IE6 and below, plus whether control contains any text
            mainobj.$control.css({width:mainobj.$control.width()}) //IE6- seems to require an explicit width on a DIV containing text
        mainobj.togglecontrol()
```

---

То вот строка в нем управления самой кнопкой:

```
.css({position:mainobj.cssfixedsupport? 'fixed' : 'absolute', top:mainobj.controlattrs.offsety, right:mainobj.controlattrs.offsetx, opacity:0, cursor:'pointer'})
```